# Spread out array values that are too close

Tags: algorithm, vba, optimization

I have a list of values in an array (which is ordered low to high), I am planning to show these values distributed on a line, but as some of the values are close, the points end up overlapping. As the exact values are not important, small adjustments doesn't matter, I'm trying to make some code which spreads any clusters of values so that they are note closer than .5 from any other.

For instance, let's say we have this array:

```
my_values = { 0.2, 1.3, 2.0, 2.1, 2.5, 3.6, 5.2 }
```

The 2.0, 2.1 and 2.5 are too close together, so I need to move the so they're not closer than .5 but as close to the actual value as possible. So the optimal solution would be something like:

```
my_values = { 0.2, 1.1, 1.6, 2.1, 2.6, 3.6, 5.2 }
```

Here's my code so far, which only makes a lame attempt of a solution (the actual items in the list in my code are objects with get/set functions, but the principle is the same):

```
...
last_dot = -999 'Low enough
For Each dot In my_values
    If dot.getPos <= last_dot + 0.5 Then
        dot.setPos last_dot + 0.5
    End If
    last_dot = dot.getPos
Next dot
```

There's thing I'm not sure how to solve:
I like to spread them both up and down, so the centre of any cluser is not really moved. So far every move I do just raises the value, and the last value of the cluster gets offset more than the others, prefarably any value moved upwards should have another value move downwards. Keeping the maxinum adjustment of any value as low as possible. So in the lists above when the 2.0 are move down to 1.6 it's then too close to the 1.3, so that has to be moved to 1.1, but in my code I dont know that when checking the 1.3 item. (Not sure if I explained that so anyone can understand =/)

Any help appriciated!

Comment: I think you're opening up a can of worms here - what happens when 10 numbers are close together? Do they explode out a total of 5 units away from eachother? Probably the best thing would be to check for clusters, and then maybe 'increase the zoom' by putting the units on the axis further apart. Or, do a 'zoom in' of a cluster by having that small section of the graph repeated on a new graph, with further axis.

Comment: Also - by manipulating the data like this you really are limiting the value of the visual representation of the data. On the extreme end, it may unethical to present numbers in a 'skewed' form like this; on the more likely end, it will be just a little bit more confusing. In your case, maybe a table of data, rather than a graph, would be better suited?

Comment: In addition, I would say that this is not a VBA problem, but a general one related to algorithms. The way I see it, you want to *ensure a minimum spacing between the elements while minimizing the maximal displacement among elements*. This is clearly an optimization problem, suitable for the *algorithm* tag. I suggest to edit the post and add this tag, chances are high that you will get intereresting suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Iterative relaxation on whole array:

input:

```
 { 0.2, 1.3, 2.0, 2.1, 2.5, 3.6, 5.2 }
```

function:

```
    for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++)// 100 is extreme, maybe 20 is enough for short anomalies
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < t.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            if (t[i] > t[i + 1] - 0.5)
            {
                t[i] -= (t[i] - (t[i + 1] - 0.5)) * 0.1;
            }
        }
        for (int i = t.Length - 1; i >= 1; i--)
        {
            if (t[i] < t[i - 1] + 0.5)
            {
                t[i] -= (t[i] - (t[i - 1] + 0.5)) * 0.1;
            }
        }
    }
```

Result:

```
0,2
1,00031552491128
1,61163875308098
2,1160023905259
2,66
3,6
5,2
```

Warning: O(n) is not efficient when only a few elements need to change.

Edit: corrected the codes as A.S.H. commented.

New output:

```
0,2
1,21857842635286
1,71823144559425
2,21771136663457
2,71733660405361
3,6
5,2
```

so it is looks more symmetric now being much closer to the point 2.05 which is mid point of points that are too close.

Comment: `t[i] -= (t[i] - (t[i + 1] + 0.5)) * 0.1;` Please check again, in the second loop, shouldn't this be `t[i - 1]`? Also, should the first `for` loop include both the other inner loops?

Comment: Nice, thanks, and excellent suggestion. @Erik I guess this is a way to achieve what you are looking for.

Comment: This may be converted to an asynchronous version so each element has equal importance of movement but code complexity increases.